# No bootable device — Insert boot disk and press any key on imac 2008 early and ssd drive

Tags: bootcamp

I have been research for 2 weeks for my problem.But there was no result.
i have imac " early 2008" 
I bought it second hand,When I bought this, it had both Windows 7 and MacOs .
i want to install windows 7 again so i was delete the Windows drive by bootcamp and then i tried to reinstall Windows with external DVD rom and windows sp1 64bit dvd disk. After specifying the amount of Windows space in bootcamp and restart computer automately, this error was displayed with this message : 
"iMac error: "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"
i tried USB.
i tried another windows installation disk.
i tried efi boot ( Which was frozen ).
i tried convert mbr/gpt to gpt .
i tried create uefi usb windowse 7 boot by rufus software. 
my imac is Upgraded, it had ssd single hard drive.it's dvd-rom faulty and I use external DVD-ROM

Comment: You must use boot camp to install as well.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1464100/no-bootable-device-insert-boot-disk-and-press-any-key-on-imac-2008-early-and

Comment: According to [Everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.66-20-inch-aluminum-early-2008-penryn-specs.html), the 08 iMac doesn't support 64-Windows

Comment: This can not be true becauseWhen I bought this device, it had 64-bit Windows